# Extract a value from a property in camel-context.xml

Tags: xpath, simplexml, apache-camel, xquery

The input looks like below,

```
<book author="ABC" type="Children">
    <id>123</id>
    <name>XYZ</name>
</book>
```

I have set the above in property in an xml route as:

```
<camel:setProperty propertyName="REQUEST">
    <camel:xpath>/node()</camel:xpath>
</camel:setProperty>
```

Then I do some other processing and based on the new response I want to extract the value of an author(i.e. ABC) from this Property and compare it with a element's text string from the response.

I tried a few ways using camel:xpath and camel:simple but am not able to extract the value from property.

What is the correct way to extract this property?

Answer (score 1):

To access the REQUEST property using simple you can do this:

```
${property.REQUEST}
```

To access properties using xpath:

```
<camel:xpath>
    function:properties("REQUEST")/[add your xpath expression here]
</camel:xpath>
```

More info on the properties function can be found here - https://camel.apache.org/xpath.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible using properties, but you should be able to do it with headers.

Firstly:

```
<setHeader headerName="REQUEST">
    <xpath>/node()</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

Then if you wanted to set another header with just the author value:

```
<setHeader headerName="REQUEST2">
    <xpath headerName="REQUEST" resultType="java.lang.String">/book/@author</xpath>
</setHeader>
```

Or if you wanted to evaluate the value as a `<choice>` condition:

```
<when>
    <xpath headerName="REQUEST">/book/@author = 'ABC'</xpath>
```

Comment: This headerName in xpath only works from camel 2.11 and we are using 2.10. Also, I want the above one using propery only.